Deployment in vercel
Error: No Output Directory named "dist" found after the Build completed. You can configure the Output Directory in your Project Settings.
but in my frontend folder in dist it is.
so why this problem happne
I try vercel.json in some changes but nothing happen only one error is dhow

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
